# What is the best way to set cassandra.logdir

Tags: logging, cassandra

I've place cassandra software in `/home/user`
All Log files should be placed in `/data/log`.

Cassandra has the file conf/logback.xml which includes parameters for determining of  file log paths.

For instance:

```
${cassandra.logdir}/system.log
```

What is the bay way to set or change only `cassandra.logdir` somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical way is to set it as a system property using `-Dcassandra.logdir=/data/log` . A number of cassandra properties are set in this manner, typically in cassandra-env.sh - you'll see they're configured by appending to the JVM_OPTS variable:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.logdir=/data/log"
```

Comment: this solution does not work. please look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11659

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR` environment variable to whatever you need. See the [source code](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/bf96367f4d55692017e144980cf17963e31df127/bin/cassandra#L34).

If you're using `systemd`, you can configure an environment variable in your `.service` file. Otherwise, you can add `CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR=path/to//log/dir` to your `/etc/cassandra-env.sh`. Given the order things are loaded in, it should work too:

[image]