# How to change Cassandra's outfile location?

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to change the outfile location so output.log is also saved in my custom log directory, but I do not see this option defined in neither `/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh` nor `/etc/cassandra/log4j-server.properties`.

Here is the output of my `ps`:

`jsvc.exec -user cassandra -home /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/../ -pidfile /var/run/cassandra.pid -errfile &1 -outfile /var/log/cassandra/output.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Cassandra documentation, the logging is [backed by logback](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configLoggingLevels_r.html), and the default logback.xml configuration in the cassandra server sets the logging location to `${cassandra.logdir}/system.log`. This means that you can pass the `cassandra.logdir` system property to change the location, for example:

`-Dcassandra.logdir=/tmp/log`

Here is another reference for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371550/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-cassandra-logdir).

Hope it helps,

José Luis